# binary encoding over a network

Tags: c++, binary, ascii

I was wondering if all forms of data (text and images) are translated into ASCII?

If so are there any libraries that would help me interpret random strings of binary or other forms of data such as images into plain English words?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand what you're after. And no, images and binary content aren't "translated to ASCII". Things like base64 can be used for transfer to avoid control characters, but that's not going to get you "plain English words".

Comment: You mean like 'white, white, white, white, white, red, white, white...'? :P

Comment: that is fine i am trying to send interpret random images into text for fun and send it to my server.c program.

Comment: no clue man, that is why i am asking, but then how do they travel over a network? there must be some kind of library or protocol right? like when it travels over a network.

Comment: Usually they travel over a network in binary. Text is some-kind-of-binary as well.

Comment: so ASCII for everything? not base64? if you can give me an answer confirming this i will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 encode/decode
http://www.base64decode.org/

There is many open source for this depend on the language you use:
[link](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=vi&sclient=psy-ab&q=base64+decode+library&oq=base64+decode+library&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i5i30l3.3036.4853.0.5059.10.9.1.0.0.0.514.1766.0j6j4-1j1.8.0...0.0...1c.14NIfrt-7cw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b2a3c4fc3ca0133a&biw=1366&bih=667&ion=1)

Comment: great but do you know if images travel through the network as frames or ip packets in base64? or ascii?

Comment: images will travel through network as IP packets in a form of a string. The end point need to decode the string to binary again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO, not all forms of data (text and images) are translated into ASCII (printable characters).

Sometimes binary data is sent directly in TCP streams and UDP datagrams (I assume that's the level of abstraction we're talking about).